# Backbone.js tries to fetch model after creating

Tags: rest, backbone.js

i'm working on a contact form which is sent via backbone.js:

```
r = new ContactModel(); // a simple model
r.save(data)
```

after saving model on server, it tries to fetch it via GET request which i've forbidden.

what can i do to override this behavior?

Comment: As is, you will have a POST request and that's it http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/FUzbK/ Your GET request comes from somewhere else.

Comment: turns out, it was backbone-tastypie's fault.
thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out, it was backbone-tastypie's fault.

i fixed it by restoring old Backbone.sync:

```
Backbone.sync = Backbone.oldSync;
```